# Why do we use negative mass in this question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

So there is a problem based upon the Center of mass and Moment of Inertia of continuous rigid bodies. So let's say we have a sphere of radius R and its mass is uniform throughout the system of particles. Now we cut out a smaller sphere of radius R/2 from the above sphere of radius R... Now my question is, Why can't we use another way of calculating the center of mass or moment of inertia of uniform bodies instead of using the concept of negative mass?

Comment: How is a moment-of-inertia value derived via negative mass? I've not seen that before - typically, an object is sliced into thin parts each with an infinitesimal mass, and then they are summed up while taking distance into account via integration.

Comment: @Param Varsha. I think they have used the property of linearity. Whereas, a solid ball with a smaller ball scooped out will have same moment of inertia as a solid ball without that chunk removed added to the smaller ball with negative mass.

Comment: That is just a mathematical way of representing removed mass.

Comment: Yes you can!! Only if you have a computer which can divide the given body into number of particles and knows their mass and coordinates then it could easily  give you the needed result. Obviously humans can't calculate it like that and that's the reason we use negative mass. And if you have a way of calculating then you can suggest it by answering your own question.

Comment: @Steeven , We can calculate it by using areal/volumetric densities..

Comment: This is just a technique. If the question why, then it is by a choice. You could choose another method you like. It is just that negative mass is a fast method to calculate the center of the mass or moment of inertia.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You *can* calculate the moment of inertia of a spherical shell from first principles if you like, but it is simpler to use the linearity of moments of inertia. So if MOI of small sphere + MOI of shell = MOI of large sphere then MOI of shell = MOI of large sphere - MOI of small sphere.

In the same way you *could* calculate the volume of the spherical shell from first principles, but it is simpler to say

$\displaystyle \text{Volume of shell} = \text{Volume of large sphere} - \text{Volume of small sphere}
\\ \displaystyle= \frac 4 3 \pi R^3 - \frac 4 3 \pi \left( \frac R 2 \right)^3 = \frac 7 6 \pi R^3$

Answer (score 0):

It is actually like this...
I am doing it for center of mass right now :

*ρ(Volumetric density) = M/(4/3πr³)

M = (4/3πr³)ρ

m(R/2 sphere's mass) = ρ[4/3π(r/2)³]*

Now by symmetry, we can say that the center of mass does not lie on the x-axis..

So the y-coordinates of center of mass is :

y = {[ρ*(4/3πr³)*0]+[-ρ*(4/3π(r/2)³)*r]} / {[ρ*(4/3πr³)]+[-ρ*(4/3π(r/2)³)]}

*We cancel out all the ρ variables and we equate the remaining equation
We get it as -R/(4R-1) approx ( i may have done a few errors )
Here is the attached image which I created...*
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se]! Could you please reduce and correct the formatting in your answer? If everything is bold, it's much harder to read.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/253179) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I think you were also trying to explain some detail to another answerer? That is, I don't think that this is answering your own question (which you are totally allowed to do!) but explaining it further? If so, then we are much better able to help you answer your question if you edit these details into your original question, rather than posting them as an answer to your question (which just makes us think that you don't need help anymore because you found your own answer)...

Comment: No actually the reason I showed it is for the other people.. I wanted to have a different approach in this answer, that's why I gave this answer to other people... They think about it and then give other approaches for the answers... Thank you, I will see that tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to define the MMOI out of an arbitrary shape and it involves the integrals

$$ \begin{aligned}m & =\int_{V}\rho{\rm d}V\\
\vec{{\rm CM}} & =\frac{1}{m}\int_{V}\vec{r}\rho{\rm d}V\\
{\rm I}_{0} & =m\left(\frac{\int_{V}\left(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}-\vec{r}\odot\vec{r}\right)\rho{\rm d}V}{\int_{V}\rho{\rm d}V}\right)
\end{aligned} $$

where $\vec{r}$ is the location of particle inside the volume, $\cdot$ is the inner product, and $\odot$ is the outer product.

But when you have composite shapes with elemental geometries, it is much easier to combine them using the concept of **positive or negative volumes**.

For example if $V_1$ is positive (part of solid) and $V_2$ is negative (missing material), then the above integral combine as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}m & =\int_{V_{1}}\rho{\rm d}V-\int_{V_{2}}\rho{\rm d}V\\
\vec{{\rm CM}} & =\frac{1}{m}\left(\int_{V_{1}}\vec{r}\rho{\rm d}V-\int_{V_{2}}\vec{r}\rho{\rm d}V\right)\\
{\rm I}_{0} & =m\left(\frac{\int_{V_{1}}\left(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}-\vec{r}\odot\vec{r}\right)\rho{\rm d}V-\int_{V_{2}}\left(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}-\vec{r}\odot\vec{r}\right)\rho{\rm d}V}{\int_{V_{1}}\vec{r}\rho{\rm d}V-\int_{V_{2}}\vec{r}\rho{\rm d}V}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you so much my friend :)... It's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Its a mathematical method of using negative mass, the other way is slicing the rjejcted piece , calculating the piece's mass and remaining mass of original object, and then recalculating the center of mass.

In both cases,if we take origin to be at center of original sphere, we get:

$$\vec{R_{cm}}=\frac{M(0)-\frac{M}{4}(\vec R/2)}{M-\frac{M}{4}}$$

**Interpretations:**

Negative mass method: Simply, the equation is written, as we write $R_{cm}$ equation. The negative sign comes as $M/4$ mass is negative. It is possible only in idealistic world  (atleast not in our real world so far..), and is generally *easier*.

Normal method: The rejected mass, is subtracted instead of being added, since its no longer a part of system. That's why negative sign comes.

This method is more realistic and practical according to our real world.

Hope it helped!